# export cPanel full backup using API2 and UAPI in GO

Tags: go, cpanel, cpanel-uapi

i am able to create, restore, list full backup from cPanel using API2 and UAPI but i'm not able to export created backup tar.gz file from cPanel using API2 and UAPI in GO.

```
func (c CpanelApi) GetFileActions(dir, file string, newedit bool) (GetFileActionsApiResponse, error) {
    var out GetFileActionsApiResponse
    err := c.Gateway.API2("Fileman", "download", cpanelgo.Args{
        "dir":  dir,
        "file": file,
    }, &out)

    return out, err
}
```

Comment: Adding the code was helpful, but now what error are you getting, and how is the code behaving? In what way does it not work? Help us help you!

Comment: Actually i'm using cPanel API2 and UAPI in GO but there is no option to export created backup tar.gz file from cPanel using API2 and UAPI kindly help